# Why is there a subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converges to some point $y$ in $\mathbb R^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> A subset $A\subseteq\mathbb R^p$ is compact iff for every sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ which converges to a point of $A$.

I understand the whole proof of the above theorem, except for one step in the $"\Rightarrow"$ part.

$\Rightarrow:$

A is bounded, and consequently the sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded. Thus there is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ which converges to some point $y$ in $\mathbb R^p$. **(Why is there a subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converges to some point $y$ in $\mathbb R^p$??)** Since $A$ is closed, $y \in A$.

EDIT:

Our Compact Definitions and theorems covered are:

> 1. A subset $A$ of $\mathbb R^p$ is compact if each open cover $A$ contains a finite subcover.
> 2. Heine, Borel, Lebesgue Theorem: A subset $A$ or $\mathbb R^p$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded.

We covered the following Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorems.

> **Bolzano Weierstrass for Sets**
>
> Every infinite subset of $\mathbb R^p$ that is bounded has at least one accumulation point.
>
> **Bolzano Weierstrass for Sequences**
>
> 1. Every bounded sequence in $\mathbb R^p$, with an infinite range has at least one accumulation point.
> 2. Every sequence in $\mathbb R^p$ with a finite range has at least one limit point.

Comment: Sounds like Bolzano Weierstrass theorem. You should specify which topics you covered in class.

Comment: Is this a theorem, or the definition of compactness?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM - We covered 2 BW variations. I will edit them in now

Comment: It is like a pigeonhole principle applied again and again. Split a box into smaller parts, at least one will contain an infinite number, etc, etc.

Comment: @copper.hat pigeonhole ? I see it rather as successive extraction.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM - I edited it now. Can you please show me how it links to this theorem? :)

Comment: What's the definition of compactness you use?

Comment: One approach: given $x^{(k)} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, find a subsequence whose first components are monotone; find a subsequence of that whose second components are monotone, etc. Then all the components are monotone, and so by the boundedness the result is convergent (in $\mathbb{R}^n$, not necessarily the set you want).

Comment: @egreg - Edited in now

Comment: @Mathemagician Since $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence, it has an accumulation point, say $l$. Can you prove then the existence of a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ that converges to $l$ ?

Comment: So you know that $A$ is closed and that the sequence has a limit point. Then this limit point belongs to $A$ and a subsequence converges to it.

Comment: @Mathemagician $p$ is a limit point of a sequence if and only if there is a subsequence converging to $p$. This is standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A \subset \Bbb R^p$ be compact. Let $(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb N^\times}$ be a sequence in $A$. Since $A$ is compact, $A$ is bounded by Heine-Borel, so the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb N^\times}$ is bounded. By Bolzano-Weierstrass, our sequence has an accumulation point $x$. So for every ball $\Bbb B(x, \epsilon)$ we have inifinitely many elements $x_k \in \Bbb B(x, \epsilon)$. Choose a $x_{n_1} \in \Bbb B(x, 1)$. For every $k \in \Bbb N_{\geq 2}$ you can now choose a $x_{n_k} \in \Bbb B\left( x, \frac 1 k \right)$, such that $n_k > n_{k-1}$. This means, that we have found a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in \Bbb N^\times}$ of $(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb N^\times}$, which converges to $x$. Since $A$ is compact, $A$ is also closed by Heine-Borel, so $x \in A$.